# How can I get an Item code from an Invoice in Xero's API?

Tags: php, api, invoices

How can I get an item code from invoices? I'm working on php and I'm trying this
$Code = $invoice->LineItems->ItemCode;

and

$Code = $invoice->LineItems->LineItem->ItemCode;

But that doesn't work. How can I get it then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A paged request was necessary to get the Item Code field.

Answer (score 0):

LineItems will be an array of LineItem elements, so you need to access the Array element(s) you want the code from:

Loop over all line items:

```
foreach($invoice->LineItems as $LineItem){
   $code = $LineItem->ItemCode;
   /* do something with the $code */
}
```

Or to access the first Line Item:

```
$code = $invoice->LineItems[0]->ItemCode;
```

Note, I do all my Xero API work in Python, so I haven't tested this in PHP, apologies if I've made a syntax error, the approach should be sound.

Comment: Thanks bro, but I tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's because it's an XML object, have you tried $invoice->LineItems->children() ?